# Convert string list to float list and then sum

Tags: python

Im just started to use python and need yours help please.
I have a text file with 13 columns, in the 13's column I have numbers like `71.78 , 84.44 , 58.68` and etc.

I select the column and convert it to list:

```
['71.78', '84.44', '58.68', '70.15', '58.39']
```

after that I tried to convert to float to do a sum but it did not worked.

this is my code:

```
import csv
with open('cust.txt', 'r') as file: 
    file.readline()
    prices = [cols[13] for cols in csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")]
    prices_list = (str(prices))
    floats = [float(x) for x in prices_list.split(" ")]
    print(sum(str(floats)))
```

I will be glad for help, thanks.

Update: My error is:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['98.14',"

Comment: *Did not work* is a bit terse; what happened? `str(floats)` will convert the list to one string, which is hard to sum; this is probably not what you imagine.

Comment: please post your error message if possible

Comment: Update: My error is: ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['98.14',"

Comment: Why do you convert the list to a string and then split the string to iterate over it? Can't you just iterate over the list?

Comment: I read somewhere to do it after I tried withous split, I tried to convert list to float and then sum, I will glad for other solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need this code to achieve what you want:

```
floats = [float(x) for x in prices_list]
print(sum(floats))
```

Comment: You could do it even shorter with sum(float(i) for i in my_list). It is even more scaleable since it uses generators

Comment: still : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['

Comment: did you remove the `split()`? You don't need it

Comment: Yes I removed it , but still not worked.. did u have any idea please

Comment: I think you have to remove this line `prices_list = (str(prices))`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
prices = ['71.78', '84.44', '58.68', '70.15', '58.39']
floats = [float(x) for x in list]
print(sum(floats))
```

EDIT: Here is another approach reading the csv.

```
with open('cust.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    prices = [cols[1] for cols in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")]
    floats = [float(x) for x in prices]
    print(sum(floats))
```

To directly get a list of floats use just cast directly, when building the prices list.

```
with open('cust.txt', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    prices = [float(cols[1]) for cols in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")]
    print(sum(prices))
```

Comment: Its works if I write the numbers like this. but if I take them from column its didnt worked :/

Comment: Ah you didn't say that the values are not just floating point numbers. Could you give a sample line from the text file?

Comment: When I wrote the new program that you showed mw its wrote : IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Does your file contain lines where the particular column is not set or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. if the CSV file has 13 columns, then the last column is `cols[12]` and not `cols[13]`.
2. with `prices_list = (str(prices))` you convert the whole list to one string (actually a tuple that contains only that string). In the next statement you are splitting this string using a space as separator, but that does not remove other characters such as the brackets, quotes and commas. That's why the conversion to float fails.

It helps to print the intermediate results (or use a debugger) to see what your program is doing and determine where the problem is.

The following code is a working example, assuming your CSV data is tab-delimited, has 13 columns, and the last column contains the floating point data you're interested in.
Since I don't have your CSV file, I used a StringIO object with test data. A StringIO behaves just like a file, so the code should work the same with your CSV file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import io  # just for the test data since I don't have the CSV file

TEST_DATA = """
a\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th\ti\tj\tk\tl\t71.78
a\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th\ti\tj\tk\tl\t84.44
a\tb\tc\td\te\tf\tg\th\ti\tj\tk\tl\t58.68
"""

print(TEST_DATA)

#with open('cust.txt', 'r') as file:
with io.StringIO(TEST_DATA) as file:
    file.readline()
    prices_as_str = [cols[12] for cols in csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")]
    print('prices_as_str: ' + repr(prices_as_str))
    prices_as_float = [float(x) for x in prices_as_str]
    # Alternatively you could use map():
    # prices_as_float = list(map(float, prices_as_str))
    print('prices_as_float: ' + repr(prices_as_float))
    print('sum: ' + repr(sum(prices_as_float)))
```

This has the following output (with tabs reduced to 6 characters to decrease line width):

```
a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     71.78
a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     84.44
a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     58.68

prices_as_str: ['71.78', '84.44', '58.68']
prices_as_float: [71.78, 84.44, 58.68]
sum: 214.9
```